# Swap columns inside every other row with Views and Bootstrap

Tags: theming, views

i want to create block with views.I want style output like image bellow. 
Sorry i add  image because my english is not good and i cant explain what i want

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to customize the view output to include the necessary [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) classes. Once you have done that, all is needed is a small bit of CSS.

**Remove default formatting**

Turn off default formatting in your format settings. (If using *Unformatted list* format, uncheck "Provide default field wrapper elements".)

**Add column classes**

[Rewrite the output of your fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578524) to include column classes `col-xs-12 col-md-6`. Example:

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">[field_image]</div>`

*This assumes you have two fields: one for image and another for text.*

**Add row class**

[Override the views template](https://www.interworks.com/blog/carmstrong/2013/02/27/quick-tutorial-overriding-drupal-views-using-templates) for rows (e.g. views-view-unformatted.tpl.php) to include `row` class in the wrapper element. Example:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="row <?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print $classes_array[$id];  } ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Output**

If you are using *Unformatted list* as your view format, your mark-up will look something like this:

```
<div class="row views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    ...
  </div>    
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    ...
  </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

Now all you need to do is add some CSS to your theme's stylesheet that emulates Bootstrap's [push/pull column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) **in only the odd rows**; e.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 970px) {
  .view-testing .views-row-odd div:first-child {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .view-testing .views-row-odd div:last-child {
    right: 50%;
  }
}
```

Edit: An alternative is to use [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap), as suggested here by Alex, but you will still need to override the mark-up to alternate column ordering per row.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) and implement it using the grid.

> Views Boostrap module enables you to create components following the theme structure of the Bootstrap framework all within the configuration settings of the powerful Views module.

Comment: Hey, cool. I didn't even know this module existed. Much better (and simpler) answer.

Comment: Although, hold on - I wonder if Views Bootstrap provides settings to alternate column ordering per row? I think this is the larger part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I would use the default views classes with striping (under format settings) and use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or float the image with CSS on your `.views-row.odd` and `.views-row.even`.

Note: Untested and from memory but should be really close.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is so old, it has certainly been solved by now. However, for anyone else who comes along, https://www.drupal.org/project/views_parity_row will solve this through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but if you use now Bootstrap 5, you can use the CSS `order` property. Let's say your column has `col-lg-6` class :

```
.container-view {
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
       .col-lg-6 {
           &:first-child {
            order: 2;
       }             
     }
   }
 }
```

**Documentation :**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order